# Find the type of boost python object

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I have been embedding python into c++ and I would like to know if there is a way to find the
type of the boost::python::object which is a result after executing a function of a python module. I have my code like this:

```
boost::python::object module_ = boost::python::import("..libName");
boost::python::object result_ = module_.attr("..functionName")(arg1, arg2,...);
//suppose if the result is int,
int a_ = boost::python::extract<int>(result_);
```

From the above code snippet, what i would like to know is if there is way to find the type
of the result before extracting it. In the above code, the result_ might be any type like list, tuple...

Answer (score 13):

You can try this

```
std::vector<std::string> list_to_vector(boost::python::list& l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len(n); ++i)
    {
        boost::python::extract<boost::python::object> objectExtractor(l[i]);
        boost::python::object o=objectExtractor();
        std::string object_classname = boost::python::extract<std::string>(o.attr("__class__").attr("__name__"));
        std::cout<<"this is an Object: "<<object_classname<<std::endl;
    }
    ...................................................
    ...................................................
 }
```

It works for me.

Comment: Worked for me, I was getting 'N5boost6python3api5proxyINS1_13item_policiesEEE' when using typeid...

Answer (score 5):

Since you seem to want to check if it's an integer, you can use [`extract<T> x(o)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/extract.html#extract-spec):

```
boost::python::extract<int> n(o);

if ( n.check() )
    // it's an integer, or at least convertible to one
else
    // not an integer
```

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/extract.html#extract-spec) says:

> extract x(o); constructs an extractor whose check() member function
>   can be used to ask whether a conversion is available without causing
>   an exception to be thrown.

This may sound as if a float may be deemed *convertible to integer*, but I tried it, and it doesn't. In other words, I wouldn't really trust that it does the right thing every time!

For built-in types, in this case an integer, I think it's more safe to use [`PyInt_Check`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_Check), but at least when *I* tested some code here, it wasn't immediately available.

In other words, if you need to determine the type of objects that are not Python built-ins, I'd follow [@Aereaux's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17119739/21028) of using [`PyObject_IsInstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsInstance). (But I'd personally like better to have a clean Boost Python code base, rather than a mix.)

Comment: As you suggested it's not reliable. extract<bool> will happily accept integers

Comment: Yes. Since this post, I've realized that `extract` will try to automatically convert between compatible types. The way to be sure it's exactly an integer is to use `PyInt_Check`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple ways to get the type of an object.  Which one you use depends on what format you want the result to be.  You could use `result_.attr("__class__")` to get the class as a boost::python::object.  You could also use the [PyObject_IsInstance function](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_IsInstance) to check if it is the type you think it is.  Last, you could use the [PyObject_Type function](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_Type) to get the type of it as a PyObject*.